# db.listCollections() does not work in mongodb6.0.3

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I used mongodb version < 4. Now I needed to install mongodb on ubuntu 22, the easiest way was to install version 6.0.3
But now some of the functionality does not work, for example

```
db.listCollections()
```

-There were no problems, but after upgrading to mongodb6.0.3 - it does not work. I read that it is advised to use

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Are these functions interchangeable? Is there no difference between them?
And is it possible to make `db.listCollections()` work in version 6.0.3?

I read [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#request-opcodes)  that many functions are already outdated in version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.listCollections()` was a convenience wrapper in the legacy shell.

To get the same behavior in mongosh, use the [listCollections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#listcollections) database command, like

`db.runCommand("listCollections")`